unable to move the data folders of my nextcloud serve to a external thumb drive
The question is, how to move data folders in nextcloud to thumb drive.
I bought a raspberry pi 5 and did setup a nextcloud on it via portainer.
I have only very basic knowledge in linux and none with portainer or docker.
I've installed portainer and nextcloud successfully and from a bit of testing, nextcloud seems to work perfectly fine.
If I move the data and try to access the nextcloud website, it's reachable, but shows an internal server error message only.
I'm able to move the data folders such DB, Config, Data of nextcloud, within the raspberries main drive / SD card.
With these steps works as follows:

Go to portainer and stop the nextcloud stack
In the portainer "editor" tab, edit the 3 paths as .../Nextcloud/DB, .../Nextcloud/Config, .../Nextcloud/Data to new location within the same main drive and SD card.
Then mv the folders via sudo mv .../Nextcloud .../<NextcloudNewLocation>
Starting the stack, via update the stack in portainer

If I do the same with the paths changing to my thumb drive /media/.... it doesn't work, which I mentioned above returning internal server error.
I formatted the thumb drive via "GParted" to ext4 then changed the thumb drives access permissions using sudo chmod 777 . to allow any users as
ls -l drwxrwxrwx <target>
Found nextcloud-snap page that described which seems irrelevant to my case in the following nextcloud page.
To summary, nextcloud-snap issue is, not allowed to access the /media folder and one must enable "the removable-media plug".
I couldn't get this problem with "regular" nextcloud instead of "nextcloud-snap".

It seems my problem was a simple hardware problem.
I was able to fix the problem by simply switching to another thumb drive.
